# How many of the Quarter Quell tributes were in on the plan?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In *Catching Fire*, the second book/film of the *Hunger Games* series, there is a very special Hunger Games in which

> all the tributes are victors of previous games, and several of them are conspirators in a rebel plan involving destroying the arena, and escaping to District 13 to participate in the uprising.

**How many of the tributes were in on this plan?** It's clear that Beetee, Finnick, and Johanna at least were part of it, and probably also Wiress and Mags, although not Katniss and Peeta. Do we ever find out exactly who the in-arena conspirators were?

Comment: 6 upvotes, then suddenly 2 downvotes in the last hour. Care to explain? Anything I could do to improve this question? (I'm beginning to wonder if my serial downvoter has a sock...)

Comment: do what I do. Every question downvote (last couple of weeks, someone downvotes nearly 100% of my questions) spurs on a new question. Some of them end up on NHQ list with attendant rep gain. Best revenge is to repcap well :)

Comment: Excellent question! And it gave @DVK another chance to throw some lists around :)

Comment: @Mooz - I never managed to get to depth 3 nestedness :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Maximum: 12.
- Realistic maximum: 10 (2 most likely didn't know)

  - Knew certainly: 4
  - Knew likely: 2 more
  - Unknown: 4

> There was a plan to break us out of the arena from the moment the Quell was announced. The victor tributes from 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, and 11 had varying degrees of knowledge about it. (*"Catching Fire", Ch 27*).

So, we have:

- District 3 Male: **Beetee**

  - Knew.
  - He made up the plan to blow the forcefield.
- District 3 Female: **Wiress**

  - Unknown but likely not
  - Given her mental state, it's likely she wasn't told for same reason Katniss and Peeta weren't
- District 4 Male: **Finnick**

  - Knew
  - He was one of the leaders and organizers of the plan
- District 4 Female: **Mags**

  - Knew, most likely
  - She sacrificed her life to keep Peeta alive in the poisonous fog, when Finnick couldn't carry both her and Peeta.
  - > As I stand there, weapons ready, I can't lose the uneasy feeling that something is going on and that it has to do with Peeta. I retrace our steps, starting from the moment the gong rang out, searching for the source of my discomfort. Finnick towing Peeta in off his metal plate. Finnick reviving Peeta after the force field stopped his heart. Mags running into the fog so that Finnick could carry Peeta. The morphling hurling herself in front of him to block the monkey's attack. The fight with the Careers was so quick, but didn't Finnick block Brutus's spear from hitting Peeta even though it meant taking Enobaria's knife in his leg? And even now Johanna has him drawing a map on a leaf rather than risking the jungle...
    >   There is no question about it. For reasons completely unfathomable to me, some of the other victors are trying to keep him alive, even if it means sacrificing themselves. (*Chapter 23*)
- District 6 Male: **Male morphling**

  - Unknown.
- District 6 Female: **Female morphling**

  - Knew, most likely
  - Sacrificed her life to save Peeta
  - > I run for Peeta, to knock him to the ground, to protect his body with mine, even though I know I won't make it in time
    >   She does, though. Materializing, it seems, from thin air. One moment nowhere, the next reeling in front of Peeta. Already bloody, mouth open in a high-pitched scream, pupils enlarged so her eyes seem like black holes.
    >   The insane morphling from District 6 throws up her skeletal arms as if to embrace the monkey, and it sinks its fangs into her chest. (*Chapter 21*)
- District 7 Male: **Blight**

  - Unknown
- District 7 Female: **Johanna Mason**

  - Knew
  - She cut out Katniss' tracker
  - > “Johanna knocked you out to cut the tracker from your arm and lead Brutus and Enobaria away from you,” says Haymitch. (*Chapter 27*)
- District 8 Male: **Woof**

  - Unknown but likely not
  - He was out of it, same logic as Wiress.
  - > Woof, a really old guy who's hard of hearing and doesn't seem to know what's going on since he keeps trying to stuff poisonous bugs in his mouth (*Chapter 16*)
- District 8 Female: **Cecelia**

  - Unknown but likely yes
  - Because Woof likely didn't know, and at least one person from district 8 was known to be aware to a degree. Also, she was very friendly to Katniss.
- District 11 Male: **Chaff**

  - Unknown in the books.
  - Wikia says he deliberately sacrificed himself to protect Peeta from Brutus. But that did NOT happen in the books, and @rand said it didn't happen in the movie. So we'll assume Wikia made that up.
  - He tried to be friendly with Katniss before the Quell and was Haymitch's friend. So there's a chance he knew.
- District 11 Female: **Seeder**

  - Unknown.
  - She died too early to tell.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, sir. So that's Wiress, Beetee, Finnick, Mags, the morphlings, Johanna, Blight, Cecilia, Woof, Chaff, and Seeder.

Comment: @randal'thor - sorry, was doing major edits. See update. Will try to hunt up quotes for more

Comment: "In the movie [Chaff] deliberately sacrificed himself to protect Peeta from Brutus" - sorry, nope. I watched the film only last week. We see nothing of Chaff after the start of the Games until his picture appears in the sky on the final evening. (I could also nitpick e.g. over the fact that you've chosen different wording for Mags and the female morphling, but I'll wait until you've finished editing ;-) )